# Node.js and Jade Source Code Seems Terrible

Tags: node.js, templates, pug

The problem is when i use node.js and jade template engine, my source code seems terrible on browser , i mean codes are in just one line , is there a solution to fix that.

source codes on browser seem like that :https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1SDM.png

Comment: codes are in 1 line not like on html structure

Comment: you probably enabled html compression

Comment: i dont think i did that , if i did how can i disable it :S

Comment: finally solution is adding  app.locals.pretty = true; that on server file